# Firestore structure and rules for multiple groups and users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm having trouble coming up with the best solution for a multiple groups and users setup in Firestore.

Below you can see the structure and rules so far and it works pretty well until a group wants to list all members by name, how should the rules be setup for that?

Or do you recommend a different structure for my setup?

```
users: [
  "userId" {
     "name" : "Name",
     "groups" : ["groupId", "groupId", "groupId"]
    }
]

groups: [
  "groupId" {
     "name" : "Name",
     "members" : ["uid1", "uid2", "uid3"]
    }
]

contacts: [
  "contactId" {
     "name" : "Name",
     "owner" : "groupId"
    }
]
```

Firestore rules

```
function member(groupId) {
  return request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupId)).data.members;
}

match /users/{userId} {
  allow read; // <---  how to allow only same group members to read?
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userID;      
}

match /groups/{groupId} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
  allow write: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.admins;
}       

match /contacts/{contactID} {
  allow read: if member(resource.data.owner);
  allow write: if member(request.resource.data.owner);
}
```